# Delete row from database in gridview and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using gridview with edit and delete button.

When i delete particular row in gridview, it will be removed. but again i reload the page, the deleted row again displayed. I mean, row is not remove in database.

Here is my code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                int index = gr.RowIndex; 
                hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString(); 
                Textid.Text = gr.Cells[1].Text;
                Textusername.Text = gr.Cells[2].Text;
                Textclass.Text = gr.Cells[3].Text;
                Textsection.Text = gr.Cells[4].Text;
                Textaddress.Text = gr.Cells[5].Text;
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;      
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);
                var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());                
                GridView1.Rows[id].Visible = false;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");

            }
        }
```

and asps file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
        EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                SortExpression="Section" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
               <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnedit" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditRow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle BorderColor="#CCFF66" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
          <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btndelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="Deleterow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>            
        </Columns>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FF66FF" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

storedprocedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE StoredProcedure4
    (
    @id int 
)
AS
begin
Delete from Student where id=@id
End
```

I'm new to .net. can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Put your SP "StoredProcedure4" code here.

Comment: com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", gr.Cells[0].Text); replace this line in your code.

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: no. not getting any exception@Imad

Comment: @Rani, Are you getting what value in "gr.Cells[0].Text"?

Comment: i checked using break point. it shows as null, here is screenshot http://s18.postimg.org/lo5pfy6p5/untitled.jpg

Comment: @Rani, Pass id as command argument in delete button and access it on code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative way could be,

**Short answer**
Pass ID using commandargument

**Full answer**

Replace

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btndelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="Deleterow"></asp:Button>
```

By

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btndelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Deleterow"></asp:Button>
```

in aspx and in cs

Replace

```
       else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;      
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);
                var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());                
                GridView1.Rows[id].Visible = false;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");

            }
```

By

```
     else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
            {     
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());                
                GridView1.Rows[id].Visible = false;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");

            }
```

Comment: remove that line because you are redirecting in the end. So it does not affect

Comment: after removed that line . next line shows error like this http://s13.postimg.org/elc11n26f/untitled.jpg

Comment: Have you removed that?

Comment: I told you to replace your code and mine. my code don't have `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);` so remove that.

Answer (score 0):

pass parameter not valid `@id` change `@ID`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE StoredProcedure4
(
    @ID as int=0 
)
AS
begin
Delete from Student where id=@ID
End
```

Comment: I don't think capitalization matters

Comment: after follow your answer, even in my gridview can't able to to delete

Answer (score 0):

Pass Id as command argument in delete button and access on code behind like below.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
      <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btndelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Deleterow"></asp:Button>                    
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>


else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
        {     
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
            var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());                
            GridView1.Rows[id].Visible = false;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");

        }
```

Comment: Copied version of my answer

Comment: @Rani, Remove this line "GridView1.Rows[id].Visible = false;" no need to hide this because it's already deleted.

Comment: yes..again shows error.. s13.postimg.org/elc11n26f/untitled.jpg

Comment: @Rani, Which exception?

Comment: @Rani, Ok i got it please remove this line also "com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94302/discussion-between-kaushik-maheta-and-rani).

Comment: @Rani, are you there?